# Avoid repeating .each() in jQuery when going through object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refactor my `$.each()` so I don't have to repeat this step to simply fetch JSON of different categories.

JSON--

```
var data = {
"categories": {
    "cat1": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "code": "6001",
            "name": "Item 1",
            "size": "M";
        }
    ],
    "cat2": [
        {
            "id": "232",
            "code": "60021",
            "name": "Item 31",
            "size": "";
        }
    ]
}
```

}

At the moment I'm doing `$.each()` for each categories which is kinda annoying as then I have to maintain two separate codes see example below. Then I have two append each category in their respective `div` Id

```
$.each(data.categories.cat1, function(index, value) {
    var itemHtml = '<div>value.name</div>' // sample only
    $('#cat1').append(itemHtml);
});

$.each(data.categories.cat2, function(index, value) {
    var itemHtml = '<div>value.name</div>' // sample only
    $('#cat2').append(itemHtml);
});
```

So I thought doing something like this would work, but clearly it didn't.

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
 var itemHtml = '...';
 if(data.cat1) {
   $('#cat1').append(itemHtml);
 } else if(data.cat2) { 
   $('#cat2').append(itemHtml);
 }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this without repeating `$.each()` everytime as they will have the same HTML layout anyway.

Comment: each iterates through an object ... you can't iterate through multiple objects at the same time

Comment: What you have isn't JSON and even if it was, it wouldn't be valid. It seems like your data might actually look like `{cat1: [...], cat2: [...]}` ?

Comment: sorry edited, I put my correct object.

Answer (score 2):

`$.each` allows you to iterate over objects and arrays. If you iterate over an object, you get the property name and the property value passed to the callbak. Assuming your data is actually `{cat1: [...], cat2: [...]}`, you'd do:

```
$.each(data.categories, function(category, items) {
  // `category` is either "cat1" or "cat2"
  // `items` is an array

  var $element = $('#' + category);

  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    var itemHtml = '<div>Layout</div>' // sample only
    $element.append(itemHtml);
  });

});
```

There are potentially better ways for generating and appending the HTML, depending on your actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on properties:

```
$.each(data.categories, function(index, value) {
    console.log(index); // current category
    $.each(value, function(indexSub, valueSub) {
        console.log(indexSub);
        console.log(valueSub.id);
        console.log(valueSub.code);
        console.log(valueSub.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to do it in a fairly simple way

```
Object.keys(data.categories).forEach(function(cat) {
  var itemHtml = '<div>Layout</div>'
  $('#' + cat).append(itemHtml)
})
```

Comment: how is this different from using `$.each()`? But will still have to do an `$.each(data.categories[cat])` to get the data `value.x`?

Comment: I was just going off your two last code snippets, for which my example is much simpler.  Nowhere in your question have you specified anything about `value.x`, so you might want to make your question a little clearer.

Comment: Yeah sorry just realised that I thought I added it in my `itemHtml` var. I've added it now.